# How to use lenses to look up a value in a map, increase it or set it to a default value

Tags: haskell, state-monad, lenses

While working on a state called `AppState` I want keep track of the number of, say, instances. These instances have distinct ids of type `InstanceId`.

Therefore my state look likes this

```
import           Control.Lens

data AppState = AppState
  { -- ...
  , _instanceCounter :: Map InstanceId Integer
  }

makeLenses ''AppState
```

The function to keep track of counts should yield 1 when no instance with given id has been counted before and `n + 1` otherwise:

```
import Data.Map as Map
import Data.Map (Map)

countInstances :: InstanceId -> State AppState Integer
countInstances instanceId = do
    instanceCounter %= incOrSetToOne
    fromMaybe (error "This cannot logically happen.")
              <$> use (instanceCounter . at instanceId)
  where
    incOrSetToOne :: Map InstanceId Integer -> Map InstanceId Integer
    incOrSetToOne m = case Map.lookup instanceId m of
      Just c  -> Map.insert instanceId (c + 1) m
      Nothing -> Map.insert instanceId 1 m
```

While the above code works, there is hopefully a way to improve it. What I don't like:

- I have to evoke the map `instanceCounter` twice (first for setting, then for getting the value)
- I use `fromMaybe` where always `Just` is expected (so I might as well use `fromJust`)
- I don't use lenses for the lookup and insertion in `incOrSetToOne`. The reason is that `at` does not allow to handle the case where `lookup` yields `Nothing` but instead `fmap`s over `Maybe`.

Suggestions for improvement?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The way to do this using lens is:

```
 countInstances :: InstanceId -> State AppState Integer
 countInstances instanceId = instanceCounter . at instanceId . non 0 <+= 1
```

The key here is to use `non`

```
 non :: Eq a => a -> Iso' (Maybe a) a
```

This allows us to treat missing elements from the instanceCounter Map as 0

Answer (score 5):

One way is to use the [`<%=`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.12.3/docs/Control-Lens-Lens.html#v:-60--37--61-) operator. It allows you to alter the target and return the result:

```
import Control.Lens
import qualified Data.Map as M
import Data.Map (Map)
import Control.Monad.State

type InstanceId = Int

data AppState = AppState { _instanceCounter :: Map InstanceId Integer }
  deriving Show

makeLenses ''AppState

countInstances :: InstanceId -> State AppState Integer
countInstances instanceId = do
  Just i <- instanceCounter . at instanceId <%= Just . maybe 1 (+1)
  return i

initialState :: AppState
initialState = AppState $ M.fromList [(1, 100), (3, 200)]
```

which has a "partial" pattern that should logically always match.

```
> runState (countInstances 1) initialState
(101,AppState {_instanceCounter = fromList [(1,101),(3,200)]})
> runState (countInstances 2) initialState
(1,AppState {_instanceCounter = fromList [(1,100),(2,1),(3,200)]})
> runState (countInstances 300) initialState
(201,AppState {_instanceCounter = fromList [(1,100),(3,201)]})
```

Comment: I feel like I haven't fully understood `at` yet ... now the `Just ... Just` looks redundant. I gotta experiment some more, but that's indeed what I was looking for.

Comment: OK, so the key for me was to understand the [alter](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.6.3/docs/Data-Map-Strict.html#v:alter) function that has in its signature a function `Maybe a -> Maybe a` to set or unset map values.

Comment: And in terms of improvement, glguy's answers tops yours. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

I would use

```
incOrSetToOne = Map.alter (Just . maybe 1 succ) instanceId
```

or

```
incOrSetToOne = Map.alter ((<|> Just 1) . fmap succ) instanceId
```

I don't know if there's a lensy way to do the same.